# System hang - freeze when installed 2 set KIT ram

Tags: memory, freeze, dual-channel

Original my system:

- MOBO: GA-Z68XP-UD3R (rev 1.3)
- CPU : Intel Corei7 2600 (3.4GHz)
- VGA : GV-R6750OC-1GI
- POW : ACBel 510W
- CPU-Cooler: Cooler Master Hyper 412 Slim
- RAM:: Kingston 4GB (2x2GB) 1866 KIT - (KHX1866C9D3K2/4GX)

It's first build and I have been using it for several months and my system worked fine.

But, when I bought the exact same memory, from the same vendor and installed it, Windows 7 system started to hang.

I even re installed Windows 7x64 and yet Windows 7 freezes randomly.

I has tried bumping up the RAM voltage, fixed DRAM TIMING as per specs (Profile1-1866: 9-11-9-27 or AUTO).

But the bug still occurs!

After installing a set of KIT 4GB (2x2GB),system is working fine.

If I install 2 sets of KIT 8GB (4x2GB) system hangs and freezes randomly!

Is there anyway to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is awfully specific and I doubt it will help anybody else as you asked it. But let me answer it in a more generic way.

Q:
I have a system a pair of memory DIMMS. These work.
If I put in a different pair they also work.
If I put both in they do not work.

A:
If you load the memory system with more modules you put it under more stress.

Your CPU supports the following: `Memory Types: DDR3-1066/1333` ([Source: Intel](http://ark.intel.com/products/52213)).
If you run these at 1866 then you are out of spec for your CPU. You might get lucky and it might work. It also might not work.  You just added more stress to the memory subsystem.  Guess what...

Comment: Doesn't the RAM run at the spec's speed unless it's overclocked?

Comment: I have little knowledge about the hardware, ram bus depend to MOBO support, and CPU also supported?

Comment: @r.tanner: Yes, that would be sane and is probably the default. But why would the OP buy RAM kits specifically designed to be much faster than needed and not try to use the extra speed? Granted, that was an assumption on my part. I did not look up if `Profile1-1866` runs the RAM at speeds faster than 1333. It seems a safe guess though.

Comment: @Hennes It's not uncommon for a higher speed RAM to actually be cheaper sometimes. In fact, I have some in my system just like that. Doesn't mean it isn't the problem however, it very well could be.

Comment: Aye. Faster kits seem to sell better. Stocks seem to be bigger and prices lower. Somewhere this feels insane, but that is just how the market sometimes works. But if you do OC the RAM and you get errors then the safe thing would be not to OC and see if the problems go away.